# How to display html text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

I have to display html text as like android provides Html.fromHtml to display htmltextview does flutter provides anythings to display html text?

Answer (score 8):

There are packages that do this

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter inline browser view
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html renders a HTML subset in Flutter directly

Comment: flutter_html is not working in all tags include that which they provides.

Comment: As I said a "subset". Translating from HTML to Flutter widgets isn't trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html:
```

**Currently Supported HTML Tags:**

*a, abbr, acronym, address, article, aside, b, bdi, bdo, big, blockquote, body, br, caption, cite, code, data, dd, del, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, figcaption, figure, footer, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, i, img, ins, kbd, li, main, mark, nav, noscript, ol, p, pre, q, rp, rt, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, template, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var*

**Example Usage:**

```dart
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: [
      new Html(
         data: "<b>Hai</b>,
          defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
       ),
     ],
)
```

Comment: This is great if you want to hard code your html into your app, but if you're pulling from firestore and you need different styling for different documents (or if you want to make your text selectable), this plugin does not work.

Answer (score 1):

***Inline styling works in this package***

```
import'package:flutter_widget_from_html_core/flutter_widget_from_html_core.dart';//add dependencies pubspec.yaml


Html("your_html_text",
textStyle: TextStyle(),//not required
);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.